# How to make internal article links in Joomla?

Tags: hyperlink, joomla, joomla-article

I'm trying to create a link in one Joomla article that points to another article, but can't see how this should be done.

Could you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can link to it like this:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=ARTICLE_ID
```

Comment: You might want to also add ItemId=ID to set the correct menu item to be highlighted.

Comment: @Christopher :) removing italic html tag? really :) ... I don't know if Joomla still uses this logic. In any case, you should have explained what exactly you changed. This said, it does look better this way, but we shouldn't have revived it

Answer (score 3):

Use the [JCE Editor](http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/editor). Then follow these steps.

1. Select the 'link' option
2. Select browse/content
3. Select the content item
4. Select 'insert'.

This is one method, but there are many others. The example uses Joomla 2.5 but the same process is used in Joomla 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

**To create internal linking between different div or p just create links like this**

```
<a href="index.php/component/content/article?id=96#div1">Go to div one</a>
```

> Note: must add full URL of current article and then add **#name**.

```
<div><a name="div1">Here is div one</a></div>
```