# Linking article pages on joomla that do not exist as a menu item

Tags: joomla, hyperlink

How do we link an article page on Joomla without it being published as a menu item? We have tried using the ID number, but it does not work.

For example, within one of our published pages we want to link to another article page but this page does not exist as a menu item- so there is not an url to use.

Please provide step-by-step instructions.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4072704/1983389 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/26462875/1983389

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to **NOT** have to create URLs manually you can try switching the editor that Joomla uses by default (TinyMCE). Personally I find **JCE Editor** much more useful. With that you can quickly generate links to menu items, content or even contacts all from their 'Insert/Edit Link' modal popup. It also has a more robust image manager. JCE Editor can even be installed from the 'Install from Web' tab of the Extension Manager Install page.